# How to address The Commissioner General of an authority

Tags: communication, salary, employer-relations, manager

I am the class president of a customs and tax (revenue) administration school in a country x.

The last lot (2yrs ago) the remuneration for the trainees was double, almost triple our current stipend. We have analyzed the stipend by deducting taxes and also considering worst cases for rent, commuter and meals and we have found that its difficult to manage the money - it's little for one living in a city. I have been advised by the school management (the school is not autonomous and its under the parastatal) to write a letter to the Commissioner General to consider our plea for stipend increase and of course by highlighting the dissatisfaction point by point. The HR department cannot talk on our behalf because it was the reason for the change!

How can I write a polite letter yet citing all our grievances without burning bridges with the CG?

Apparently we are guaranteed of full employment with by the Authority upon completion of the 1 yr training.

Comment: I feel your question could use either a bit more context or a bit more generalisation to make it broader. In general, I would advise writing objectively and using facts supported by examples. In your case, I would detail the workload of the trainees and the ballpark of the costs they will run into and set that against the stipend they are receiving. If the numbers don't add up, this will become apparent. As long as you stick to the facts and leave emotions out of the discussion I don't think any bridges will be burnt.

Comment: Obviously country specific without listing the country

Answer (score 1):

The comment by @Cronax hits the main idea, talking from facts that can be supported by evidence, such as examples.

**Example:**

> The request for the increase is based on an example for a typical trainee, "Peter." Peter's expenses tabulated below are based on average (representative) expenses for all trainees from the current year. The calculations are based on the sample of n=X trainees at our school for the academic year 2014-2015.

[Here you include a table with expenses and costs, maybe separate costs into brackets by low margin, average, and high margin columns to illustrate a range of possible costs experienced by most trainees).]

Expense Type; Expense bracket: low / medium / high; other variables?
1. ...
2. ...
3. ...

Other variables may include proportion of trainee stipend (based on average expense); and/or comments with 1-2 bullet points with additional information or context, such as demographics (e.g. avg distance traveled used for calculating transportation expense).

In addition to the "anecdotal" (though analysis-based) example above, other useful supporting data may include a bar or line graph showing increase in the cost of living over the past 2-3 years (variable 1), contrasted with decrease in annual trainee stipends that you mentioned (variable 2). Use public, government-released data if possible, and include a citation to the source (e.g. government website or municipal report).

In general, as has been mentioned, make sure to speak from principles and objectively verifiable data rather than subjective interpretation (e.g. claims such as "these costs are too high").

Also include an introductory paragraph and a conclusion, where you briefly summarize the key points with which you are trying to persuade your audience, namely:

- The combination of the declining stipends and rising cost of living
  results in a level of support for trainees that is insufficient for covering living expenses over a sustained period.
- The insufficient funding causes other hardships such as X, Y, Z. (cite specific problems trainees experience).
- The combination of the hardships caused by insufficient funding result in ...(report the major consequence of these problems, such as increasing number of trainees dropping out of the program, or declining trainee performance/grades, or declining retention after completion of the course of study).

Hope this helps, and good luck!